# What is a Hostess Set of flatware?

Tags: equipment, cookware

When talking about flatware, what exactly does a Hostess Set include? How many people does it serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Oneida.com:](http://www.oneida.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/content.page/nodeID/5548532f-1b21-4460-94c1-aaeb0c3f6468/)

What is in a Hostess Set, Serving Set and an Entertainment Set?

A simple way to remember what pieces are in a Hostess Set is: The word Hostess starts with an "H" everything in a Hostess Set holds something.

- Hostess Set: Gravy Ladle, Tablespoon, Sugar Spoon
- Serving Set: Serving Fork, Butter Knife, Pierced Tablespoon
- Entertainment Set: Casserole Spoon, Dessert Server

Comment: Does this mean that Hostess Set is for one person?

Comment: @Roman: No it means the host set is not a place setting at all, but a collection of specialty tools that you generally need only one or two of at the table. Similarly with the other sets that Michael lists.

Comment: Are you sure that this is what a "hostess set" is, or is it just what Oneida identifies as such in their product line? Searching around other shopping sites for "hostess set" yields varied results, the most common being a serving spoon, fork, slotted spoon, and spreader. In particular, the ladle seems to be *mostly* unique to Oneida's "hostess set" ([for example](http://www.wayfair.com/Flatware-Serving-Pieces-l1038-c419105-O8332~Hostess+%5BS%5D+Serving+Set.html) - not intentional spam, btw, it just happens to be a representative result).

Comment: (Another example: http://www.silverqueen.com/Info/Sterling%20FYI presents a definition which agrees with most search results but conflicts with Oneida: *"The standard serving pieces  sometimes sold as a 6 piece hostess set are the A. Table serving spoon; B. Pierced Tablespoon; C. Cold Meat Fork; D. Sugar Spoon; E. Master Butter Knife;  F. Pie Server."*)